# Failed to replace 'if' statement with 'switch' statement in jquery

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, popup

I have some page with multiple pup-ups on it, so when user clicks on preview – correct full picture appear.
This is html:

```
    <tr class="rowLicense">
 <td class="bigPop licensePopUp" ><img src="images/license/license_1.jpg"></td>
 <td class="bigPop licensePopUp2"><img src="images/license/license_2.jpg"></td>
 <td class="bigPop licensePopUp3"><img src="images/license/license_3.jpg"></td>
    </tr>
```

This is the 'if' version of the script:

```
 $(".bigPop").click(function(){
            if ($(this).is(".licensePopUp")){ //заменить на свитч
                $(".popupLicense").fadeIn();
           }
            else if ($(this).is(".licensePopUp2"))  {
                $(".popupLicense2").fadeIn();
            }
            else if ($(this).is(".licensePopUp3"){
                     $(".popupLicense2").fadeIn();
            }
        });
```

it works, but seems not optimal

I tried to use 'switch', this is the code:

```
  $(".bigPop").click(function(){
              var i = $(this).is();
                switch (i) {
                    case (".licensePopUp"): 
                         $(".popupLicense").fadeIn();
                    break;
                    case (".licensePopUp2"):
                        $(".popupLicense2").fadeIn();
                    break;
                          }

        });
```

It does not work, i suppose i did some mistakes in defining 'i', or maybe in declaring statement, but i cant find a clue.

P.S. Please don't blame me, i just started to learn js, so don't know many obvious things.

Comment: Please edit your question to markup the code properly.

Comment: There is actually no difference between these two, in terms of 'optimization'.

Comment: `is` checks if the selector you pass it matches the element, it doesn't return a selector. That is why your `switch` doesn't work here. You could use something like `switch (this.className)` and `case "popup licensePopUp"` but the answers below provide better implementations.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can just do this, without any `if` or `switch`

```
$(".bigPop").click(function() {
    var num = $(this).attr("class").replace(/.*licensePopUp(\d).*/, "$1");
    $('.popupLicense' + (num ? num : '')).fadeIn();
});
```

What the above does is gets the number in the class and then concating it with that number or just empty string if the number isn't a number. Alternatively you can set a separate `data-*` attribute and then use that instead.

Answer (score 2):

You could simplify your code significantly if you used some sort of data attribute which would target specific popup:

```
<td class="bigPop" data-target=".licensePopUp"><img src="images/license/license_1.jpg"></td>
<td class="bigPop" data-target=".licensePopUp2"><img src="images/license/license_2.jpg"></td>
<td class="bigPop" data-target=".licensePopUp3"><img src="images/license/license_3.jpg"></td>
```

And JS then:

```
$(".bigPop").click(function () {
    $($(this).data('target')).fadeIn();
});
```

This approach offers additional flexibility, because now `data-target` can be any CSS selector, not only class name, but also id, etc.

Comment: I don't catch this
$($(this).data('target')).fadeIn();
it says that somethings fades in, but i dont know how to point on this

Answer (score 0):

How about this one? I tried to use the [event.target](http://api.jquery.com/event.target/).

```
 $(".bigPop").click(function(event){
          var target = $( event.target );
          target.fadeIn();

 });
```

Note I haven't tested the code yet.

Answer (score 0):

try using the switch as follows:

```
$(".bigPop").click(function(){
                var i = $(this).attr("class");
                switch (i) {
                    case "bigPop licensePopUp": 
                         $(".popupLicense").fadeIn();
                    break;
                    case "bigPop licensePopUp2":
                        $(".popupLicense2").fadeIn();
                    break;
                          }

        });
```